# URL Rewrite Optional Parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get a my original url which would have been `properties.php?bed=1&page=1&perpage=12&area=testarea` to `/search/1/1/12/testarea`. But the last query string 'area' is optional and so could be blank.

I have this so far below, the problem is if I add an extra ([^/]+)/ such and

```
RewriteRule search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? pages/properties.php?bed=$1&page=$2&perpage=$3&area=$4
```

and then don't supply an area in the url, it fails to work correctly. Is there a correct way to do this where the query sting can be optional?

Also another problem I'm having is I would like this

```
RewriteRule search-rooms/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? pages/rooms.php?bed=$1&page=$2&perpage=$3&area=$4
```

to be /search/rooms/ not /search-rooms/ but if I put an extra / after search it again doesn't work correctly and the page reads the wrong data from the URL.

This is the full version

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule property/([^/]+)/? pages/show.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? pages/properties.php?bed=$1&page=$2&perpage=$3&area=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule search-rooms/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? pages/rooms.php?bed=$1&page=$2&perpage=$3&area=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.studentlettingsagency.co.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^studentlettingsagency.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.stla.co.uk/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Handle in your PHP file

Comment: What do you mean? Currently if you visit the original page and don't pass an area query string the page will still loads correctly ignoring the area, using the mod-rewrite it causes problems and fails to load anything

Comment: Then add one more line before the existing `RewriteRule search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? pages/properties.php?bed=$1&page=$2&perpage=$3` ignoring area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search/rooms
RewriteRule search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)?/?$ pages/properties.php?bed=$1&page=$2&perpage=$3&area=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule search/rooms/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)?/?$ pages/rooms.php?bed=$1&page=$2&perpage=$3&area=$4 [NC,L]
```

`RewriteCond` is important here ,as it tells the first rule not to match the uri  `/search/rooms`

Comment: Thanks the area is now working, even is not passed in the URL, but the /search/rooms is not. When the page loads the url such as this: /search/rooms/8/1/12 instead of seeing 8 bed it's seeing rooms bed?